# Magento 2: How to center the Related Products block in product pages?

Tags: magento2, design

On Blank theme, Related Products block is aligned to the left.

How can I align the block so the products are aligned at the center of the page?

I tried using "text-align: center" but this causes the product name and price are also aligned to center. Product name and price should stay aligned left.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick solution to the problem would be to use the working code of:

```
.related .column.main .product-items {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And then correct the alignment of the product name and price here:

```
.block.related .product-item-details {
    text-align: left;
}
```

These classes are based on the use of the Luma theme in a Magento 2 install.

I did notice that there are some responsive issues with this solution. Once you get down to a mobile view the products aren't centered because of some rouge margins. That can be easily cleaned up with some playing of the values.

Comment: This approach worked in Blank theme. I'll mark it as the best answer since it is the easiest way to do it

Comment: glad it worked for ya!

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding it a bit dofficult to picture, but I think this article might help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div

See, it sounds like you want to center your  and not the contents. See how you get on.

Comment: I've already tried those but dont work. I'll update my question to include images so I can explain better

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
#category-items {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
#category-items li {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 16.666666667%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #f3dce7;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;

<div style="width:100%;float:left">
<ul id="category-items">
<li>
</li>
<li>
</li>
<li>
</li>
<li>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

You'll have to use text-align:left on your product names, probable an `<h5>` tag and you might have to wrap you price in a div box and give it also text-align:left. I think it already is in div with "price-box" class.

Anyhow, give it a try.